# How to make this UserScript run on IE10?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, internet-explorer-10, userscripts

I'm %5 in Javascript commands , so first thing is to not blame me for anything you watch.

anyway, i used IE 10 for javascripting files i have a command/file.js for ( Auto Check ToS Box ) and purchasing automaticcaly.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name AutoCheckSteamMarketToSBox
// @namespace *://www.steamcommunity.com/market/listings/*
// @include *://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/*
// ==/UserScript==


function buyitem() {
    document.getElementById('market_buynow_dialog_accept_ssa').checked = true;
}
```

and this is the purchasing button:

```
function buyItemconfirm() {
    document.getElementById('market_buynow_dialog_purchase').click();
}
```

i dont know how to open and close the commands, 
also i dont know if that script need (var) or (if) or or

anyway, what i want exactly?

**i want if the TOS box is checked, he will buy the item automaticcaly** by:

```
document.getElementById('market_buynow_dialog_purchase').click();
```

without pressing purchase button manually.

i know it's too much easy commands for javascript coders, so please help me for this script without any error if you dont mind.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a 'UserScript' (as in Greasemonkey)? What browser is this supposed to run on?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh yes its userscript but i using it before with chrome and only the checked box is working but the purchasing button didnt work ;/

Comment: Are you trying to run it in IE10, or was that about something else?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh i'm trying and i hope to run it in IE10

Comment: I don't think any version of Internet Explorer supports UserScripts (as defined by Greasemonkey). Do you have something that's telling you otherwise? Full-capability userscripts run primarily on Firefox (either GreaseMonkey or Scriptish addons). Partial-capability userscripts run on Chrome (cut-down functionality similar to GreaseMonkey) or Opera (different kind of script).

Comment: A quick google led me to IE7Pro (http://www.ie7pro.com/) This appears to allow running of some UserScripts. I don't know whether it will work with IE10.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh ahaaaa!!! this is a new thing for me 

ok , can you make it with IE10 without userscript version?

i mean can you make it from the biggening with the correct commands using 

     document.getElementById('market_buynow_dialog_accept_ssa').checked = true

as a checkedbox command 

and 

     document.getElementById('market_buynow_dialog_purchase').click();

as a buying button ?

Comment: How will you be running it? A UserScript normally works by injecting JavaScript code into some 3rd party website once the DOM is ready. How will you achieve that with IE? Do you have control of the webserver hosting the site? (www.steamcommunity.com)

Comment: @David-SkyMesh no i dont have the webserver hosting on this site, so there is no anymore chance to return userscript into javascript by collection some stable commands which are inside the source of the page like the (checkedbox) and (buybutton)?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh also forget to tell you that i'm trying before for chrome and firefox using trampermonkey and Greasemonkey and only the checked box is working alone.

Comment: What you've posted isn't even a whole UserScript. We can't check why it might be wrong without the whole code.

Comment: ok bro , i uploaded to you a winrar included 2 files:

the source of the buying page 
the userscript file but its corrupted ( randomly automatic buying )

i hope i got it with javascript , if not: with userscript will be fine.

here is the file

     http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/442479/help-rar.html

Comment: Please just edit your question and paste the entire UserScript (javascript) file inline. It's much harder for other people (than me) to help you if they have to follow these comments.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I want to highlight that you can run Userscripts in IE with TrixieWPF45 (a clone of Trixie). It works with IE11 on Windows 8:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45/

It is not the simplest to use, ei. when you develop userscripts you have to reload them via the Trixie settings panel to refresh the scripts.

Additionally you can use IE7Pro (disregard the name, it does work with later versions of IE)
http://download.cnet.com/IE7Pro/3000-12512_4-10649334.html

But it is a much larger plugin and more bulky

Comment: how do you open the trixie settings panel? i cant seem to find it, the trixie website is not much help either.

Comment: Press the `<alt>` key to get the Internet Explorer menu, select `Tools` and then `Trixie Options`

Comment: thanks, got that working. but the trixie options menu isnt showing any scripts, it should have the default script in there, though it also didnt create the config xml file in the installation folder after it was installed, so i guess its a permissions error. damn this is so fiddly, no wonder they called it trixie lol